# Insert set value into MySQL database not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to attempt to insert the work "Peach" into my 'trees' table where there are the following fields:

ID (Auto Increment)
owner_id
tree_type  (this is where i want "PEACH" added)
tree_height
tree_ammount
active

Heres the script

```
<?PHP

session_start();

include 'src/sql_handler.php'; 

include 'src/tree_handler.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitPeach'])) {

$array = array('tree' => $_POST['tree'],);

$handler = new Tree_Handler;

$handler->addPeach($array);

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<input type="image" src="images/tree/Choose Fruit/fruit1.jpg" name="submitPeach" />    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My sql_handler is fine, i know this because all its used for is connecting to the MySQL DB, which works with all my other scripts fine.

Here is the tree_handler.php

```
function addPeach($array) {

    $SQL_CON = new MySQL_Con;

    $SQL_CON->MySQL_Con();

    $tree_type = 'Peach';

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO trees(owner_id, tree_type, active) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($data['ID'])."',[Peach],[0])") or die(mysql_error());

    if (!$query) 
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error();
echo "Added";
die($message);

    $SQL_CON->End_Con();

}
```

My issue here is when i click on the fruit1.jpg picture it acts like its loading, but does nothing, inst inserting anything into the table nor giving me an error message. Do i HAVE to use all columns when inserting into a table or am i aloud to only pick the owner_id, tree_type, active columns

**MASS EDIT:**

i want to match the email of the user, then add the ID of that user. (There us a column called ID in the users table which is the auto increment in the users table) carried over to the trees table owner_id column. then insert the word Peach into the tree_type column, and if its active or not which right now would be 0 because its not active, once the user clicks that peach and it appends, there's still those tree_height and tree_ammount columns that are being left NULL until they are taken to the next screen where they have a fun way to interact with the tree they chose to pick the height of the tree, but that's a whole other story and different page. Just thought i would let you know the FULL process.

Comment: you want to insert $data['ID'], 'Peach' and 0 right ?

Comment: i did a mass edit on the original post as it is valuable information, please read it

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO trees(owner_id, tree_type, active) VALUES
('".mysql_real_escape_string($data['ID'])."','Peach',0)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: i dont see a difference between your code provided and mine... explain please.

I see the brackets were removed from peach and 0... is that really nessissary? Can you explain why? Not saying your wrong, just want to know why so i get a better understanding of the code. I am new to PHP

Comment: You are trying to insert like `[Peach],[0]`; which is not correct.

Comment: so if its a number use nothing, if its a text string then use the ' ' around the word? Am i understanding that correctly?

Btw i tried that, and it didnt work.

Comment: @AaronRussell, that's correct. BTW, `it didnt work` is not a proper error definition. You need to tell what didn't worked? What error did you get if any?

Comment: It didnt work, as in... same nothing, no error, just clicks and does nothing, well, it reloads the page. Visit it for yourself if you dont mind, teknologenie.com/fruitforest/picktreetype.php

Comment: @AaronRussell, I would suggest you to debug your whole code and see exactly where it's failing. Issue you mentioned is not present in the posted code but rather in some other place.

Comment: i noticed i called a variable `$tree_type = 'Peach';` would exchanging the VALUE Peach with the variable make a difference? Or is it essentially the same process?

Comment: @AaronRussell, no it will not make any difference, I posted another comment above; see that.

Comment: I will give it another go then and start from scratch. Thank you